# I need to return if btnYes is pressed

Tags: java, javafx

```
public class StartPeriodMessage extends Stage implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private  Button btnYes = new Button();
    @FXML
    private boolean btnYesStatus = false;

    public StartPeriodMessage(){

        try {

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().
getResource("/fxmlFiles/StartPeriodMessage.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);

            Parent root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);

            setScene(scene);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void handelYesBtn(){

        setBtnYesStatus(true);
        this.close();
    }

    @FXML
    public void setBtnYesStatus(boolean btnYesStatus) {
        this.btnYesStatus = btnYesStatus;
        System.out.println(btnYesStatus); // prints true

    }

    public boolean isBtnYesStatus() {
        return btnYesStatus; // returns false     
    }
}
```

```
public class WorkPeriodController extends Stage implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private void handlebtnStartPeriod() throws InterruptedException{
       StartPeriodMessage spm = new StartPeriodMessage();
       spm.initOwner(this);
       spm.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
       spm.show();

       if (spm.isBtnYesStatus()) // always false {

            btnStartPeriod.setDisable(true);

            // do some actions
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write @FXML everywhere! Only if you reference from your fxml file to the method/variable.

If you reference a variable like btnYes from your FXML-file it is initialized there and not in your class.
Where do you load your fxml file? if the following (I just cleaned it up) is not working, please also provide your fxml file and the code where you call isBtnYesStatus();

```
@FXML
private  Button btnYes;
private boolean btnYesStatus = false;

@FXML
private void handelYesBtn(){
    this.setBtnYesStatus(true);
    this.close();
}

public void setBtnYesStatus(boolean btnYesStatus) {
    this.btnYesStatus = btnYesStatus;
    System.out.println(btnYesStatus);
} 

public boolean isBtnYesStatus() {
    return btnYesStatus;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, @FXML was confused to me, Now i understand when to write it.

Comment: But  it not working i will attach the fxml and the code

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting this link. So you are creating a new `StartPeriodMessage` and call .show() on it. Then you immediately calll isBtnYesStatus(). Due to the default false initialisation of btnYesStatus it will always return false. and after that you can click your button and the boolean changes.This cannot work correct, but it is not really a bug because It is wokring as you coded it. For this Usecase you should implement a Callback!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set action event to your button like below :

```
  @FXML
    private void btnYes(ActionEvent event) {
    // your action here..
    System.out.println(Button is pressed..);
  }
```

And you dont need to go for the initialization part FXMLLoader will do it for you

```
@FXML
private Button btnYes = new Button();
```

Comment: The Application consists of many stages and this is a pop message stage to check if the user click yes it will do some actions in another stage so i need to return if button yes is pressed or not. if you not understand me, i can share the screen via team viewer. Thanks!